# Can a C file compiled from CGo code, be imported into Cython?

Tags: c, client-server, cython, cgo

Is it possible to 'include' a C file compiled from CGo (C+Golang) code, into Cython (C+Python)  ?

If not, is there any other way to access Golang API hosted on a server, from Python clients ?

*Planning to deploy a server-client architecture, with a Python client, Golang API in a server, database in another server*